# A mathematical programming problem

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have an optimization problem as follows.

Given an array of positive integers, e.g. `(y1 = 2, y2 = 3, y3 = 1, y4 = 4, y5 = 3)`, I aim to maximize the sum of the values of functions `f(x)`, where `f(x) = x if x + y <= m` and `f(x) = 0` otherwise. (`m` is a positive integer)

For example, in this particular example above (with `m = 5`), the optimal `x` value is `2`, as the sum would be `2 + 2 + 2 + 0 + 2 = 8`, which is the highest among other possible values for `x` (implicitly, possible `x` would range from `0` and `5`)

I can of course exhaustively work out and compare the sums resulted by all possible x values and select the x that gives the highest sum, provided that the range of x is reasonably small. However, if the range becomes large, this method may become excessively expensive.

I wonder if there is anything I can use from things like linear programming to solve this problem more generally and properly.

Comment: You answered the question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Standard_form. Could you specify the particular problem, may I don't see?

Comment: I don't understand your problem statement. Where are you getting the value for y?

Comment: You asked 10 question and NEVER voted. Are all the answers you received undeserving an upvote?

Comment: @Igor: the example above can be a particular problem, though the specific values of the array and m can vary. This is why I asked for a more robust and general solution. Thanks for the wiki page and I will look into it...

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: y can be seen as the array y = (y1, y2, y3,...,yn). In the example above n = 5. Another variable m determines the 'upper bound' of the sum between x and yi (i from 1 to n), beyond which the value of function f(x) = 0

Comment: @belisarius: err... I believe I have though I don't think I voted for a proposed solution in every question I asked... Excuse me for being mistaken, but I thought the point of voting here is to let the OTHERS judge the quality of the solution. As the original poster of the question, my primary role is to pick the one that I think is the best, which in most cases would be one receiving the most votes from others. I can of course vote myself, but isn't that redundant provided that I will pick the same solution too. Correct me if I get this wrong.

Comment: @belisarius: cool, thanks for pointing this one out.

Comment: @Igor: I had a look at the standard form of linear programming but it doesn't seem to fit into the problem I have above. For example, how I should define the constraints here if I set the objective function to the sum of fi(x), where i ranges from 1 to n, corresponding to y = (y1, y2,...,yn)? Thanks.

Comment: @skyork: sorry can't help you with this. try to repost at http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://mathoverflow.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for linear programming here, just a sort and a single pass to determine the optimal x.

The pseudocode is:

```
getBestX(m, Y) {
    Y = sort(Y);
    bestSum = 0;
    bestX = 0;

    for (i from 0 to length(Y)) {
        x = m - Y[i];
        currSum = x * (i + 1);
        if (currSum > bestSum) {
            bestSum = currSum;
            bestX = x;
        }
    }

    return bestX;
}
```

Note for each `i` we know that if `x = m - Y[i]` then `f(x) = x` for every element up to and including `i`, and `f(x) = 0` for every element afterwards, since Y is in ascending order.

Comment: This is a good solution, as the sort provides the nice property that veredesmarald outlined above. Though the answer solves the question programmatically, I wonder how we can solve this numerically as a mathematical problem.